# Close server button problems

Tags: java, multithreading, syntax

I am new to java. I start my server with a button

```
    JButton startServerButton = new JButton("Start");
    startServerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) {
                Runnable serverRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runServer();
                    }
                };
                Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverRunnable);
                serverThread.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

and I want to close it with a button

```
    JButton endServerButton = new JButton("End");
    endServerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("End")) {
                closeConnection();
            }
        }
    });
```

but the close button doesnt work... Please help! Here's the close function

```
private void closeConnection() {
    displayMessage("\nTerminating connection\n");
    try {
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is in other code which you have not posted. What is the error, precisely?

Answer (score 0):

Try these options:

**1)** Put **End** operation in a new thread and then close the **Start** thread' IO & then socket connection. (Means closing the 1st thread socket connection from another thread)

**2)** In the **End** operation thread, set **Start** thread' socket timeout.

Regards,